# Prototype and substr

Tags: javascript, prototype, substr

I'm trying this prototype, i'll add more things there inside prototype, what's I'm doing wrong?

```
String.prototype.replaceme = function(){
    var toreplace;
    toreplace = this.substr("&lt;","<") 
    toreplace += this.substr("&gt;",">");
    return toreplace;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it looks like you are trying to perform a replacement, so you should be using [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) instead of `substr()`:

```
String.prototype.replaceme = function() {
    return this.replace("&lt;", "<").replace("&gt;", ">");
}
```

That being said, there are probably better ways to [decode HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+decode+html+entities).

Comment: Edited as i need, this is the solution i looked for:

return this
  .replace("&lt;", "<span style='color:#c0c0c0;'>&laquo;", this)
  .replace("&gt;", "&raquo;</span>");